# Apache multiple Virtual hosts document Root not working

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

Hello I try to do test that

```
ubuntu 20.04.01 APACHE : 192.168.23.136
win10  20H2            : DHCP

glpi : /var/www/glpi/index.html
test.com : /var/www/test.com/public_html/index.html
   
file : 000-default.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Win10 browser Web
192.168.23.136/glpi : it work
192.168.23.136/example.com : it doesn't work
192.168.23.136/example.com/public_html : it work
```

Can you tell me why I can't see my web page in example.com

Comment: You should access you virtual host using the web address: `http://example.com/` . Of course, before that, you should add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file like this: `192.168.23.136 example.com`; otherwise, your browser will go to the _real_ `example.com` web site.

Comment: It works thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

From this [source](https://serverfault.com/questions/363215/apache-virtual-hosts-with-multiple-locations-with-multiple-document-roots-is-i), I find it difficult to see how it works with 2 DocumentRoot for the same IP and port. The following might do:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerName mydomain.no-ip.org
    
    #Default site, accessible by http :// mydomain.no-ip.org/
    <Location />
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/alias"   
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Location> 
    
    Alias /mail /usr/share/squrrelmail 
    #Squirrelmail, accessible by http :// mydomain.no-ip.org /mail  
    <Directory /usr/share/squrrelmail>   
        Options FollowSymLinks
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                php_flag register_globals off
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
             DirectoryIndex index.php
        </IfModule>
        <Files configtest.php>
                order deny,allow
                deny from all
                allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```